# How can we get tenant id, client id and client secret for Azure Function App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I am going use key vault for Azure Function App.

I am using .NET SDK.

1. Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets
2. Azure.Identity

Example:

```
string keyVaultUrl = configuration["KeyVaultSettings:Url"];

            TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
#if DEBUG
            credential = new ClientSecretCredential(configuration["AZURE_TENANT_ID"],
                                                    configuration["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"],
                                                    configuration["AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"]);
#endif

            var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential);
```

To debug locally I need

> tenant_id, client_id, and  client_secret.

How Can i get this?

Comment: Refer this [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) to get tenant_id, client_id. However you cannot retrieve client_secret from portal. You can try by creating a new client_secret

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have **Authentication** turned on in your Function App. Go to **App Registration** of the function app and for steps to fetch `Client Id`, `Tenant Id` and `Client Secret`, you can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) and [this](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Identity-Manager-Tips/Creating-the-application-Client-ID-and-Client-Secret-from/ta-p/1776619).